# Ajax só tem retorno caso eu coloque um "echo" em vez de "return" no php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou construindo uma aplicação utilizando ajax (jquery) e php, ao retornar um json pelo php, o jquery só pega o valor caso eu tenha dado um ECHO, caso eu retorne o json atraves do return (estou utilizando uma função no php) o jquery não pega nada.

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL+action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        if(result.sucesso && !result.redireciona){
            sucesso(result.mensagem);
        }

        if(!result.sucesso && !result.redireciona){
            erro(result.mensagem);
        }

        if(result.redireciona)
        {
            location.href = result.link;
        }else {
            botao.prop("disabled", false).val(textBotao).css('opacity', '1');
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        botao.prop("disabled", false).val(textBotao).css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```

php:

```
public static function draw(){
    $return = ["sucesso" => false, "redireciona" => false, "mensagem" => "Dados incorretos"];
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

se eu substituo return json_encode($return) por echo json_encode($return) funciona normalmente

Alguém sabe me dizer se realmente deve acontecer isso? obrigado

Comment: Pra um arquivo ser considerado um `json`, o seu conteúdo deve conter um padrão de formatação `json`. Quando você faz um `echo` você está escrevendo no arquivo, um return está apenas retornando um valor que pode ser guardado e usado em algum lugar (guardado em uma variável por exemplo). Resumindo, o `echo` vai preencher o arquivo, o `json_encode` vai deixar os dados que você está usando pra preencher o arquivo em um formato `json`. O `echo` é usado para escrever no arquivo, o `return` não..

Comment: @RickPariz mas já vi aplicações que usam o return para voltar os valores da requisição ajax e funcionar normalmente, por isso estou estranhando.

Comment: Dependendo da estrutura (se for algum Framework sei lá), você da apenas um return e no fim de tudo a estrutura chama algum método para imprimir na tela.. não sei.. eu particularmente nunca usei e nunca vi o return ser usado para devolver dados para uma requisição ajax.

Comment: Ah entendi, provavelmente deve estar acontecendo isso então, obrigado!

Comment: O return não exibe os valores, por exemplo, caso vc utilize o laravel, tem que utilizar uma função para retornar o json  `return response()->json($return);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comunicar do PHP para o javascript é preciso fazer através de uma saída de texto (echo/print) ou outras funções (lembre o http é um protocolo baseado em texto). O mais correto é deixar o return no final do método e na hora de chamar `draw()` adicione o echo.

Pode simplificar o método para:

```
public static function draw(){
    return  json_encode(["sucesso" => false, "redireciona" => false, "mensagem" => "Dados incorretos"]);
}
```

Na hora de chamar:

```
echo classe::draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

Bem, a chamada ajax lê a resposta do servidor e essa resposta deve ser processada como algum tipo de dados legíveis, como `application/jsonou` ou `text/html`.

Para escrever esses dados, você precisa `echo` do servidor com o PHP.

A declaração de retorno não grava dados, ele simplesmente retorna no nível do servidor.

[respondida no site em ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107144/difference-between-php-echo-and-return-in-terms-of-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.return.php o `return` é uma estrutura de controle da linguagem PHP, portanto use-a exclusivamente no PHP para retorno de valores ou retorno para o próximo ponto de execução.

O `echo`, de acordo com http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php está caracterizado como uma função de string (apesar de não se comportar como uma função). O que ele faz é escrever as strings no buffer de saída.

No seu caso o jQuery chama o PHP através do seu servidor HTTP aguardando uma saída em json deste servidor HTTP. E para fazer isso você deve escrever no buffer de saída, portanto isto justifica o por que o `echo` funciona e o `return` não.